# Two 3d models on one image tracker

Tags: android, android-ndk, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am developing an Android AR aap on Vuforia Qualcomm SDK, for which I have to do animation in which one model jumps and sticks to another model, something of [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&NR=1&v=g714VOyUpDc) sort. This has to happen on the marker whenever the app detects one.

I have two questions:
1: What tools should be used to Animate for the models, just like shown in the video.
2: How to render two models on one marker (Target) viz. Heart and Teddy just like in the video.

Any clue or links would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question? What does Vuforia have to do with this?

Comment: @Joetjah: As I have mentioned that above, I will repeat that for you. Two things:
1)Animation for models as it has been done in the video??
2)How can I have two models on one target.

Do you have any experience in AR and Vuforia?

Answer (score 0):

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R01m6A-Wli4) shows it is possible. If I understand correct, when the webcam (and code) spots the marker, it will create an object (like the dragon from the video or the heart from your example). If that object contains an animated object, and you've ticked `Animate on create` (or something like that, I can't start Unity at my work so I'd have to check later), the animation will start. I guess that is what you asked in the first point. If not, elaborate it. You don't ask what you want as goal. You want to animate your objects? You want to animate your objects on start? Do you want to place your objects with an animation on the marker?

For the second part, you can see in the video that an `ImageTarget` object is being used. In there, he placed an animated object (the dragon) and a second object, the flames. In your case, you can add the Heart-object and the Teddy-object to the same `ImageTarget`.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Vuforia SDK 1.5 and Unity on Mac to develop an AR app for Android OS.
What I want is whenever I focus the marker from my android device's camera, the heart takes a jump and sits on teddy's head. A single heart not those many of them as shown in the video.

Comment: Seems like a fun project to do to learn how to use Vuforia and Unity3d. Good luck!